# Why wont the page size change in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, printing

I am trying to change the page size to a no 10 envelope. but all my searching has turned up no real help. the printer always says letter. when it attempts to print. Below is my latest attempt to change the paper type.

```
Public Sub printEnvelope(envprinter As String, envpaperwidth As String, envpaperheight As String, addressinfo As String)
       Dim pn As String
       Dim ps As PaperSize
       stringdata = addressinfo
       ps = DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize
       pn = PrinterSettings.PrinterName
       RectType = 6
       PrinterSettings.PrinterName = envprinter
       Dim ps1 As New PaperSize()


       DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.RawKind = PaperKind.PrcEnvelopeNumber10


       DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = True


       Print()
       'PrinterSettings.PrinterName = pn
       'DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = False
       'DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = ps


   End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The default object types provided by .net were not recognized by the printer.  I had to iterate through the paper size types provided by the driver. like below.

```
 Public Sub printEnvelope(envprinter As String, envpaper As String, addressinfo As String)
        Dim pn As String
        Dim ps As PaperSize
        stringdata = addressinfo
        ps = DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize
        pn = PrinterSettings.PrinterName
        RectType = 6

        For Each ps2 As PaperSize In PrinterSettings.PaperSizes
            If ps2.PaperName = envpaper Then
                DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = ps2
            End If



        Next

        PrinterSettings.PrinterName = envprinter
        '  Dim ps1 As New PaperSize()


        '  DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.RawKind = PaperKind.PrcEnvelopeNumber10


        DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = True


        Print()
        PrinterSettings.PrinterName = pn
        DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = False
        DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = ps


    End Sub
```